# Is it possible to run 2 different minecraft worlds with 1 modpack in each?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

Is it possible to say, I have 1 world with like enigmatica light (the modpack) and say, I want to have another world with X life (the modpack) Is that possible to have both modpacks in my mods folder, if so can someone please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

[MultiMC](https://multimc.org/) is the alternate launcher developed with this purpose primarily in mind - maintaining multiple Minecraft instances and versions with different sets of mods/modpacks.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only have 1 modpack running at a time, and you will have to switch modpacks to play on worlds with different modpacks.